# Utilize multiple cores for Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following Python (2.7) function using Pandas which I need to run on 400 GB.
A test run on 150 GB took 4 hours to complete successfully (memory on machine is 128 GB and 16 cores, 4TB disk).
Is there a smart way to utilize all the cores on my CPU for this
and doing this action in parallel to decrease the process time:

```
def create_data(headers, filters, filesFolder, remove_chars, outputFolder):
for ds in headers:
    for data_file in glob.glob(filesFolder + '*' + ds + '*.csv'):
        x=0
        for data in pd.read_csv(data_file, sep = '€', names = headers[ds], engine = 'python', chunksize = 10000000):
            logger.info('Pandas Read %s' %(str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file)) )
            for fil in filters[ds]:
                try:
                    data[fil] = data[fil].astype('O')
                    data = data[data[fil] == filters[ds][fil]]
                    logger.info('Filtered data for %s succesfully. Filters are %s' %(str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file) , filters[ds]))
                except:
                    logger.info('Could not apply filter %s for %s' %(filters[ds][fil], str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file) ))
                    pass
            for char in remove_chars:   
                try:
                    data = data.replace({char: ''}, regex=True)
                    logger.info('Removed char %s from %s succesfully' %(char, str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file) ))
                except:
                    logger.info('Could not remove char %s from %s' %(char, str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file) ))
                    pass
            try:
                data.to_csv(outputFolder + ds + '/' + str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file).split('.')[0].strip() + '.csv', enconding = 'utf-8')
                logger.info('Saved csv %s succesfully' %(str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file)))
                x+=1
            except:
                logger.info('Failed to Save %s' %(str(x) + '_' + os.path.basename(data_file)))
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that it's CPU-bound and not I/O-bound?

Comment: Not sure but the disks are SSD

Comment: RAM and the CPU are still orders of magnitude faster than an SSD. I suggest that you measure before optimizing.

Comment: Why do you convert everything to objects? `data[fil].astype('O')`

Comment: +1 @TigerhawkT3. Even on SSD clusters or professional PCI-e SSD-like card, CPU/RAM are way way faster. I/O are so slow, you should investigate it seriously

Comment: @Menkes, you may want to optimize your code a little bit: 1. get rid of the loop for removing `remove_chars` - do it in one shot. Try to apply all filters also in one shot. This should speed up the whole process.

Comment: @Menkes, could you post samples for `remove_chars` and `filters` parameters?

Answer (score 6):

This is an older question. However now, using [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) could be the simplest way.

Just install it and change your

```
import pandas as pd
```

to

```
import modin.pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 4):

I run into this problem often. I found the quickest way to get something going is to use a mix of [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), Python and [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/6/).

Suppose your headers and file names are in 2 files, headers.txt,

```
header_1
header_2
header_3
header_4
```

and files.txt

```
file_1
file_2
file_3
file_4
file_5
```

The following Python script is an easy CLI utility that takes one header and one file, and does something to them:

```
import click

cli = click.Group()

@cli.command()
@click.option(
    '-h',
    '--header',
    type=str
)
@click.option(
    '-f',
    '--file',
    type=str
    # type=click.File()
)
def create(header, file):
    # Do stuff with header and file
    print header, file 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    cli()
```

The following `parallel` command will run your script on all your cores for each combination of header and file:

```
parallel python example.py create -h {1} -f {2} :::: headers.txt :::: files.txt
```

The output is:

```
header_1 file_1
header_1 file_2
header_1 file_4
header_1 file_3
header_1 file_5
header_2 file_1
header_2 file_2
header_2 file_3
header_2 file_5
header_2 file_4
header_3 file_1
header_3 file_2
header_3 file_3
header_3 file_4
header_3 file_5
header_4 file_2
header_4 file_1
header_4 file_3
header_4 file_4
header_4 file_5
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 True, but GNU parallel changed my life and I never let a chance pass to proselytize :)